# Best way to make call number or send a menssage

Tags: android, sms, phone-call

what i want is onclick in name = textview it pop up a window with 2 buttons 1 button for phone call and other button for sms.

Comment: So how far you are ?

Comment: Im stucked cuz i dont know if is it possible to click on textview and pop up a window with 2 buttons

Comment: Did you try to add an onClick event to textview

Comment: Yeah it is just make one custom dailog and put that two buttons and show as dailog on click of textview

Comment: post your code, what you've done

Comment: put your code here then only any one can help yu

Comment: My code wont help atm but maybe u already helped me with alertdialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first google about it. What is **alertdialog** box then by using on button click make a call by using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phone1.getText().toString()));
```

where phone1 is a EditText
and send **SMS** like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));     
intent.putExtra("sms_body", message); 
startActivity(intent);
```

hope you got want you want